# Functional Programming : Creating a dictionary whilst merging values of duplicate keys into a list

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, map-function

Say I have the following list

`values = ["Cat" , "Mat" , "Jack", "Cord"]`

**I want to implement it using a functional approach**

How can I create an alphabetical index using a dictionary, such that the keys are the first letter of the words in the list and the values a list of words which start with that letter. i.e

```py
index = {
'C' : ["Cat", "Cord"],
'J' : ["Jack"],
'M' : ["Mat"],
}
```

At the moment, I have

```py
dict(map(lambda value : (value[0],[value]), values))

# output {'C': ['Cord'], 'M': ['Mat'], 'J': ['Jack']}
```

But `dict` replaces the value of the duplicate keys.

Comment: Does the list of words need to be sorted too? Like `["Cat", "Cord"]` or could it be `["Cord", "Cat"]`?

Comment: Not necessarilly

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(map(lambda value : (value[0],[value]), values))
```

- This will not append the words but rather just replace the earlier one. You need to append the words.

### Solution 1

Using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group all words under the same first letter.

```
from itertools import groupby

values = ["Cat" , "Mat" , "Jack", "Cord", "Apple", "Zero", "Banana", "Zebra"]

# Option 1
# index = dict((k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(values), key=lambda value: value[0]))

# Option 2. Thanks to @PaulRooney for pointing out this option!
index = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(values), key=lambda value: value[0])}

print(index)
```

```
{'A': ['Apple'], 'B': ['Banana'], 'C': ['Cat', 'Cord'], 'J': ['Jack'], 'M': ['Mat'], 'Z': ['Zebra', 'Zero']}
```

### Solution 2

Construct the unordered dictionary first then sort.

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = ["Cat" , "Mat" , "Jack", "Cord", "Apple", "Zero", "Banana", "Zebra"]

index = defaultdict(list)

for value in values:
    index[value[0]].append(value)    

index = dict(sorted(index.items()))
print(index)
```

```
{'A': ['Apple'], 'B': ['Banana'], 'C': ['Cat', 'Cord'], 'J': ['Jack'], 'M': ['Mat'], 'Z': ['Zero', 'Zebra']}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this seems like an iterative approach. I know that I need to append, but the goal is to do it using functional techniques

Comment: I updated the answer with a 1-line solution. Does it fit your requirements?

Comment: Indeed! I updated the answer to use that form. Thank you very much for pointing out :)

Comment: 2nd Solution: in last statement, index = `dict`(sorted(index.items()))   is redudant.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try.

```
dct = {
    
}

for i in values:
    if i[0].upper() in dct.keys():
        dct[i[0].upper()].append(i)
    else:
        dct[i[0].upper()] = [i]
```

output

```
{'C': ['Cat', 'Cord'], 'M': ['Mat'], 'J': ['Jack']}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this seems like an iterative approach. I know that I need to append, but the goal is to do it using functional techniques

Comment: ok, sorry about that. But I guess this is a helpful option for those who have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_alphabetical_index(values):
    new_dict = {}
    for value in values:
        try:
            new_dict[value[0]].append(value)
        except:
            new_dict[value[0]] = [value]
    return new_dict
```

Output

```
{'C': ['Cat', 'Cord'], 'M': ['Mat'], 'J': ['Jack']}
```